# Internal Implementation of IOC and DI in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Whenever spring boot application runs it sees the @SpringBootApplication annotation and runs the @ComponentScan which scans the classes with the annotations such as @Component etc and makes the object in the container.I have a little bit of idea that it might be using reflections internally to create the objects but I am not able to connect all the dots .I want to know what exact information does @AutoConfiguration gives to the container that it is able to get all the information of all the component annotated clases of any component ?
P.s. I have edited the wrong question

Answer (score 0):

First of all `@AutoConfiguration` is responsible for setting up the default configurations for a Spring boot application depending on the dependencies we have added in the pom.xml.

The thing you are looking for is `@ComponentScan` which is what performs the component class scanning within the default package and all of its sub packages. It does this by going through each class in the package and looking for the `@Component`,`@Service` or `@Repository` annotations. If any of them is present then the container adds this as a bean.

`@SpringBootApplication` internally has the `@ComponentScan` annotation added to it along with two others.

Comment: Yes , correct it looks for the @ Component @ Repository and @ Service and makes its bean. But for making the bean it has to know about the constructor and call to finally make the object. Does the @ ComponentScan has that information about the constructors of my components or it is using any other method like reflection to get that information internally. I am curious about that part. How this bean formation happens internally what all design patterns and what is the flow of this whole process?

Comment: Yes, reflection is the method by which this happens

Comment: Could you please give me more insights on what meta data does this componentScan gives to the container and how this reflection thing is internally using this meta data? what is the exact flow of this process of bean formation in the container? I tried to search the answers but could not find them .Please help